# grgit - to add new files and remove deleted files

Tags: git, gradle, grgit

we are using grgit to update files in github.

```
def grgit = Grgit.open(dir: repoDir)
    grgit.add(patterns: ['src'], update: false) // False should even add new files
    grgit.commit(message: 'Updated subsets', amend: false)
    grgit.push()
```

we checkout from git and delete, add, modify files in a directory and commit and push directory back to github.

now while we do grgit.add and keep **update:false** it Add new files but doesn't remove deleted files.
and if we do **update:true**  it doesn't add the new files and only do changes to tracked files.

how to add and remove files together like git add -A in grgit. please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grgit is based on JGit, which [does not currently have an equivalent](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/4.5.0.201609210915-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/api/AddCommand.html) to `git add -A`.

You have to do this as two separate steps:

```
grgit.add(patterns: ['src'], update: true)
grgit.add(patterns: ['src'])
```

Comment: i get this error -.

Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.NoFilepatternException: At least one pattern is required.
19:42:14  at org.eclipse.jgit.api.AddCommand.call(AddCommand.java:140)
19:42:14  at org.eclipse.jgit.api.AddCommand.call(AddCommand.java:85)
19:42:14  at java_util_concurrent_Callable$call$0.call(Unknown Source)
19:42:14  at org.ajoberstar.grgit.operation.AddOp.call(AddOp.groovy:72)
19:42:14  ... 67 more

Comment: Is it like this i need to do ?

grgit.add(patterns: ['src'], update: false)
grgit.add(patterns: ['src'], update: true)

Comment: Yep, I missed that part.